# How can I trigger React-to-Print using the print option in the context menu?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, contextmenu, react-native-web, react-to-print

I have a React component that displays a table and I am using the React-to-Print library to enable printing functionality. Currently, the printing is triggered by a button click, but I would like to enhance the user experience by allowing them to initiate the print action using the print option in the context menu (right-click).

Here's a simplified version of my component:

```
const PrintView = () => {
  const tableRef = useRef(null);
  const printRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
      if ((event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) && event.key === 'p') {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (printRef.current) {
          printRef.current.handlePrint();
          window.focus();
        }
      }
    };

    document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
    };
  }, []);

  const handleAfterPrint = () => {
    window.focus();
  };

  const handleMouseRightClick = () => {
    // How can I trigger the React-to-Print functionality here?
  };

  return (
    <div onContextMenu={handleMouseRightClick}>
      <ReactToPrint
        content={() => tableRef.current}
        ref={printRef}
        onAfterPrint={handleAfterPrint}
      />
      <table ref={tableRef}>
        {/* Table contents */}
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I have already set up the context menu event using `onContextMenu`, but I'm not sure how to trigger the React-to-Print functionality from there. I attempted to find a solution by searching online documentation and examples, but I couldn't find any specific guidance on how to achieve this integration.

My expectation is that when a user right-clicks within the component, the context menu appears and selecting the print option should trigger the React-to-Print functionality, resulting in the table being printed.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to accomplish this functionality. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible as a webpage to add a button to the context menu of the browser. You can only do that:

1. as a browser extension: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/user_interface/Context_menu_items
2. or a standalone executable that has a browser. For example via an Electron application: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/menu

It is however possible to disable the context menu of the browser and render your own context menu at the position of the mouse cursor as a fixed positioned html element.

> I would like to enhance the user experience by allowing them to
> initiate the print action using the print option in the context menu
> (right-click).

But if you do so, be aware that you not only enhance the user experience, but can also decrease the user experience for your users. Because you are removing functionality that they might regularly use in the browser's context menu.

```js
element.addEventListener("contextmenu", e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  // Render your custom context menu
  return false;
});
```